# iTunes connect screenshot issue

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

It is possible to upload screenshot to iTunes connect if the image doesn't show directly a part of the app but just an effect ?
To explain it more detailed, example:
If I have an app where I can upload to FB, can I put a screenshot in my app of the FB post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anyone can give you a definite answer. It depends, and the review team will make their decision. It sounds reasonable to me to show something that your app does, even outside of the app, in one of your screenshots.

Note that your app's executable can get approved but have its metadata rejected at review time, in which case you will only have to submit new metadata (such as different screenshots). This will take less time to review again.

Comment: This is true, the app store is very inconsistent in its reviews. In the past 6 years I've had numerous apps accepted with screenshots depicting things other than the use of the app, and today, my most recent app was rejected for screenshots having "text" added ontop of them as a caption to the screenshot. "Have fun" the text said. The funniest thing is this app was just approved with said screenshots 8 days ago, this update got rejected today when none of the screenshots had changed. First time in 6+ years I've been told I can't add text ontop of my screenshots as a caption. Haha, silly Apple

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that they are going to validate your app you can avoid upload screenshots about the Facebook part. For more information just read:

[iTunes Connect Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf)